# API Connection - username and password in ARM template

Tags: azure, api, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I want to provide username and password in the ARM template, such that it gets deployed and populated in Azure and can be seen under "Edit API Connection" in the Azure Portal.

[image]

Here is part of the ARM template:

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('connections_sql_name')]",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "Test Connection Name",
        "parameterValues": {
          "server": "[parameters('sql_server')]",
          "database": "[parameters('sql_database')]",
          "authType": "[parameters('sql_authType')]",
          "userName": "[parameters('username')",
          "password": "[parameters('password')]"
        },
        "customParameterValues": {},
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionID, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/sql')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

Server, Database and AuthType gets populated, but I cannot get the userName and password parameters to get populated in the deployment.

Comment: Use a keyvault.

Comment: how would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Edit API connection' page will not show the `Username` nor the `Password` because they are of type `securestring`.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#creating-a-connection
[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "connections_sql_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "connections_sql_name"
    },
    "sql_server": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "server201-dev-sql.database.windows.net"
    },
    "sql_database": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Incidents"
    },
    "sql_authType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Windows"
    },
    "username": {
      "type": "securestring",
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "securestring"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('connections_sql_name')]",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "Test Connection Name",
        "parameterValues": {
          "server": "[parameters('sql_server')]",
          "database": "[parameters('sql_database')]",
          "authType": "[parameters('sql_authType')]",
          "userName": "[parameters('username')]",
          "password": "[parameters('password')]"
        },
        "customParameterValues": {},
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionID, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/sql')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. I see, that must be of tupe securestring. How will one implement this in the ARM template that I have above? Just change the parameter of username and password from current type string to securestring?

Comment: @OliverNilsen - I updated the answer with the ARM template. Yes, change the types from `string` to `securestring`. As I have it, the PowerShell deployment using `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` will prompt for the two values unless you pass them as a parameter object. This is one place where you could leverage a Key Vault to store the username and password, retrieve the two values from Key Vault by PowerShell command, and pass them to the deployment. Key Vault will let you view secrets. -- You could also create a more complicated ARM template to reference the Key Vault secrets internally.

Comment: Hi, thx for the tip. I have now tried this approach from the ARM template:
"sql_database": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/azure-devops-key-vault/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/myKV"
        },
        "secretName": "API-SQL-Database"
      }
    },
    "username": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/azure-devops-key-vault/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/myKV"
        },
        "secretName": "API-SQL-UserName"
      }
    },

Comment: Getting values from KeyVault works for the sql_database parameter as it of type string and I can get the Secret value just fine from my KeyVault and it is also populated in the "Edit API connection" page in Azure Portal. The same code in the ARM template in the parameter.json file for the username which is of type securestring does not work. The value is still blank in the "Edit API connection" page in Azure Portal.

Comment: I have also tried to create a secret variable under Variables in Azure DevOps and tired to use that instead of the KeyVault and using it in the "Override template parameters" field of the Task for ARM deployment and passing in like this "-password $(API-SQL-Password)" but also here it ends up beying empty value in the Azure Portal.

Comment: It looks like that it works, as I can connect with my API connection. The username and password are not appearing in the fields under Edit API connection page, but the values are fetched from KeyVault and stored somewhere. I can definetly connect to my SQL database. This is poor UI from MS.

Comment: Happy to hear it worked. I agree with the Azure portal user experience..there are inconsistencies and areas that don't work as expected.